# Правильный вариант деструктора для чисто абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, деструктор

Доброго времени суток. Есть чисто абстрактный класс с двумя enum class перечислениями и набором виртуальных методов. Удаление объектов наследников будет происходить через ссылку на объект этого базового класса. Какой вариант оформления деструктора будет более корректным?

```
    virtual ~MasterInterface() = default;
```

или

```
    virtual ~MasterInterface() = 0;
```

В чём между ними разница с точки зрения работы кода, т.е. будет ли как-то отличаться поведение кода при удалении наследуемых объектов через ссылку на базовый класс?

**Upd:** Я наверное не совсем ясно выразил свою мысль. Хочу уточнить. Мне нужен виртуальный деструктор. Т.е. когда я буду вызывать удаление какого-то объекта я буду использовать ссылку на базовый объект. Как я понимаю при обращении к объекту наследника через базовый используется таблица виртуальных функций. Не получиться ли так что вызывая удаление базового объекта приложение не сможет добраться до деструктора конечного объекта т.к. в базовом классе нет виртуального деструктора и, соответственно, его нет в таблице виртуальных функций? Ведь приложение не чего не знает о наследуемом объекте т.к. у него есть только интерфейс базового (т.е. таблица переходов).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отличие есть, и оно интересное.

Если написать так

```
virtual ~MasterInterface() = default;
```

то будет сгенерирован деструктор компилятором и скорее всего все будет правильно работать.

Если написать так

```
virtual ~MasterInterface() = 0;
```

то деструктор не будет сгенерирован. Но и код не будет компилироваться, так как для  деструктора нужно объязательно тело. Поэтому, где то ещё в cpp файле должно быть такое

```
MasterInterface::~MasterInterface() {}
```

Студия позволяет использовать упрощенный стиль

```
virtual ~MasterInterface() = 0 {}
```

Но в чем же разница? А она в том, что если в первом случае можно создать экземпляр класса, а вот втором - нет, потому что первый будет просто классом с виртуальным деструктором, а второй гарантированно будет абстрактным (собственно что и нужно для сущности "интерфейс").

> Т.е. когда я буду вызывать удаление какого-то объекта я буду использовать ссылку на базовый объект. Как я понимаю при обращении к объекту наследника через базовый используется таблица перехода.

это популярный способ, но стандартом не оговаривается. Только называется таблица виртуальных функций.

> Не получиться так что вызывая удаление базового объекта приложение не сможет добраться до деструктора конечного объекта т.к. в базовом классе нет виртуального деструктора и соответственно его нет в таблице переходов? Ведь приложение не чего не знает о наследуемом объекте т.к. у него есть только интерфейс базового (т.е. таблица переходов).

У Вас есть виртуальный деструктор в каждом с вариантов. Дальше в тексте написан набор слов:) Приложение знает о всех своих классах. При виртуальности используется таблица виртальных функций. И даже если используется ссылка на базовый объект, таблица у него "правильная" - от нужного типа. Но если сделать "срезку", то да, все потеряется.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что разжевали. А можно как то создать интерфейс с деструктором в gcc?

Comment: просто деструктор объявите в любом подходящем cpp файле. И это хороший способ. Студийный способ хоть и красивый, но у него есть некоторые недостатки (таблица виртуальных функций может дублироваться, но умный оптимизатор скорее всего все исправит).

Comment: большое спасибо.

Comment: Ещё можно его как `inline`'овый определить в хедере — это даст небольшую экономию на вызовах без lto, а если он тривиальный, то отрицательных эффектов быть не должно, как и в случае с msvc.

Answer (score 3):

```
virtual ~MasterInterface() = default;
```

Потому как при вызове деструктора конкретного класса должен будет вызваться деструктор базового.

Comment: Даже если это интерфейс?

Comment: @mrFieldy, в C++ нет интерфейсов уровня языка.

Comment: @ixSci Я это прекрасно понимаю. Вопрос не в этом.

Comment: @mrFieldy А в чем ваш вопрос? В любом случае деструктор нужен. Вы можете вообще его не писать - ни как 0, ни как `=default`, все равно он будет сгенерирован.

Comment: @Harry я уточнил вопрос.